# Why does a second run of the same code execute faster?

Tags: sas

I'm trying to figure out why running the exact same procedure in SAS works faster after SAS has been exposed to the data, even though no temporary files are created. The example below shows two identical PROC MEANS steps, where the real time of execution decreases by over 95% for the second run. The pattern holds for a temporary version of the data set as well, but the difference isn't as stark.

```
6          PROC MEANS data = data.test;
7              var y;
8          RUN;

NOTE: There were 100000 observations read from the data set DATA.TEST.
NOTE: The PROCEDURE MEANS printed page 1.
NOTE: PROCEDURE MEANS used (Total process time):
      real time           22.69 seconds
      cpu time            1.07 seconds


9          
10         PROC MEANS data = data.test;
11             var y;
12         RUN;

NOTE: There were 100000 observations read from the data set DATA.TEST.
NOTE: The PROCEDURE MEANS printed page 2.
NOTE: PROCEDURE MEANS used (Total process time):
      real time           1.02 seconds
      cpu time            1.04 seconds
```

When I put a `_NULL_` data step at the top (so still nothing is written to the work directory) and set the data, the data step takes a long time, and then both `PROC MEANS` steps run equally quickly.

```
6          DATA _NULL_;
7              set data.test;
8          RUN;

NOTE: There were 100000 observations read from the data set DATA.TEST.
NOTE: DATA statement used (Total process time):
      real time           23.28 seconds
      cpu time            1.18 seconds


9          
10         PROC MEANS data = data.test;
11             var y;
12         RUN;

NOTE: There were 100000 observations read from the data set DATA.TEST.
NOTE: The PROCEDURE MEANS printed page 1.
NOTE: PROCEDURE MEANS used (Total process time):
      real time           0.97 seconds
      cpu time            0.98 seconds


13         
14         PROC MEANS data = data.test;
15             var y;
16         RUN;

NOTE: There were 100000 observations read from the data set DATA.TEST.
NOTE: The PROCEDURE MEANS printed page 2.
NOTE: PROCEDURE MEANS used (Total process time):
      real time           0.95 seconds
      cpu time            0.97 seconds
```

Clearly the CPU time doesn't vary by much, but why does the real execution time decrease by so much after the first run through the data, even if nothing is written to the work directory?

This was done using a made-up test data set with 100,000 observations and 1003 numeric variables.

Comment: Please ignore @Mike's answer, that allocate stack space thing is so very wrong I don't even know how to explain it is wrong, you don't even allocate stack space! WTF! Also the program's state (the memory of it and such) IS NOT persistent, that... can't even exist, programs have one entry point, main. PLEASE don't take anything from his comment and try and apply it because it is so very wrong. __I expect a downvote in retaliation but helping the OP is more important - you can take 2 rep from me, I'm here to help!__

Comment: @AlecTeal - that comment is really over the top.  If you disagree with the comment, say so, but you don't need the extra fluff.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**I assume here that the data is being sourced from a file**

It's not running faster, the file is in the OSes cache, Linux has done it since [forever basically] - not sure about other OSes not how well they do it.

Take a font for example, fonts will be read a lot - do you really want to power up the disk read a few kb then power it back down? No!

The filesystem cache keeps recent/frequently read (the exact metric can be configured) files in RAM. The data set is in RAM from the first time it was run.

If you are running a flavour of Unix you can use `time` to work out how much time a program spent in user-space (user time, actually doing stuff, not waiting for reads and such), you will find it's not different (a minor variation due to things like CPU speed changes, other stuff running..... - but not a big difference)

You can also see it, see CPU time is the same, that's the time your program spent actually doing stuff, Real time is how long from start to finish. Take CPU from Real and you get time spent not doing stuff (like waiting for file reads :)) you can see the second time it spends the same amount of time doing actual stuff, but less real time, so the stuff if was waiting for got faster - this is the definition/function/**job** of a cache.

Sorry for not saying this sooner, I totally skipped over the code blocks on the grounds of "I have no idea what SAS is" :P

Comment: SAS datasets are individual files on disk, yes.

Comment: Yeah good! Then it is Caching, I said I assume because 1) I have no idea what SAS is 2) I can't think why else a program would be faster on the second run, but I'll put "I assume" so I don't look like a tit if I'm wrong. @Joe. Given it sources data from a disk it is without a doubt caching and this answer is correct. Filesystem cache FTW!

Comment: @Joe see my edit, hope this helps! - Wait, Joe, you're not the OP, sorry! I thought you were.

Answer (score 0):

**Caching.** Most likely SAS is caching some information about the query in memory that makes it faster. Maybe it doesn't have to do as much compiling or analysis if it's able to find the results of a previous run in memory. Hard drives and memory buses make extensive use of caching as well. This "phenomenon" is extremely common in software.